# Deploying Angular + .Net Core to Azure DevOps VM

Tags: angular, .net-core, azure-devops

I'm working on an app using Angular (for frontend) and .Net Core (for backend) and was wondering how to get it to a DevOps Windows Server VM as there are no clear instructions for this on any documentation. And do I need a separate project for backend and frontend code r does a single project suffice?

In other words, I created a Windows Server VM through DevOps and need to get my Angular+.Net Core app to it.

Thanks,

[image: Error log at initial attempt]

Comment: Can you open a rdp to it and then copy your stuff?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Yes, but that still begs the same question I asked earlier "doesn't that make both DevOps and the VM out of sync? How do I then sync DevOps with the new files deployed to the VM through other means?" Someone seems to think two separate projects are needed, one each for frontend and backend, which I doubt.

Comment: No no need to create a separate package. From your screen shot I can only tell Azure devops can't access the VM machine. There is video cast on how to install asp.net application on premise. Can you following this and get idea of how to set up the similar stuff for Azure VM. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6blyzYjB11E&t=77s

Answer (score -1):

You can use [web deploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) to publish from VS to your VM. You'll of course have to enable it and might need to configure network access, but the VM will need that anyways to be used for web app.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I do that instead of deploying through DevOps, doesn't that make both DevOps and the VM out of sync? How do I then sync DevOps with the new files deployed to the VM through other means?

Comment: May be you can publish the dev builds on the VM, that way any pushed commits would trigger a build and the VM will host the latest builds